# Отключить перенос слов в jtextpane java

Tags: java

Делаю аналог виндового блокнота, застрял на кнопке "перенос по словам". Не могу найти в компоненте  jtextpane метод отвечающий за перенос по словам. В jtextarea такой метод есть, возможно и в jtextpane это как то можно реализовать?

Comment: Не можете найти потому, что его нет. Но Google полон обходных вариантов решения этой проблемы.

Comment: от гугла сюда и пришел, к знающим людям =)